# How is config_systemUIFactoryComponent from System UI overlayed by Car / TV System UI?

Tags: android, android-automotive

In [Androids System UI](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/values/config.xml;l=311?q=config_systemUIFactoryComponent%20) `config_systemUIFactoryComponent` is used to define the factory that shall be used for starting different System UI services.

```
<string name="config_systemUIFactoryComponent" translatable="false">
    com.android.systemui.SystemUIFactory
</string>
```

For TVs or Cars this is somehow overridden with own config files.

[For Cars](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Car/SystemUI/res/values/config.xml;l=21?q=config_systemUIFactoryComponent%20) this is done at `packages/apps/Car/SystemUI/res/values/config.xml`:

```
<string name="config_systemUIFactoryComponent" translatable="false">
    com.android.systemui.CarSystemUIFactory
</string>
```

From my understanding this does not follow the usual overlay approach of Android, since I cannot find any reference to this path via the Android Code Search.

The only place, where this config variable is used is in the code is [SystemUIFactory](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/SystemUIFactory.java;l=65?q=config_systemUIFactoryComponent):

```
final String clsName = context.getString(R.string.config_systemUIFactoryComponent);
```

I guess that `context` is important for deciding, from which `config.xml` to read the value from.

Where is decided, whether to take the `config.xml` from System UI or Car System UI?

Answer (score 0):

When you are building AAOS, the Car SystemUI will overlay the "Phone" SystemUI. This is done in the bp / makefile configuration files.